# Calling a method from a class in Python

Tags: python, class, methods

I know I'm just missing something simple here. I looked through other answers but couldn't find this problem.

```
>>> class Ben:
...     """Can access variable but not method"""
...     i = 320894
...     def foo(self):
...             return i
... 
>>> Ben.i
320894
>>> Ben.foo(self)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Comment: You should read [the Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/) to familiarize yourself with the basics of classes in Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't pass `self` yourself. It is a reference to an instance of the class on which you invoke that method. So, you would need to create an instance of `Ben`, and invoke that method on that instance:

```
ben = Ben()
ben.foo()
```

And instead of:

```
return i
```

you need to use:

```
return self.i
```

Comment: You should point out that the class atribute of `i` is being returned solely because the instance attribute `i` does not exist in the OP example. If you want unambiguously to have the class value of `i` you should use `return self.__class__.i` otherwise the instance value is returned if it exists.

Answer (score 3):

You need to instantiate a class instance in this case and invoke the method from that.

```
>>> class Ben:
    """Can access variable but not method"""
    i = 320894
    def foo(self):
        return self.i

>>> a = Ben()
>>> a.foo()
320894
```

**P.S** - You don't pass `self` as an argument and you have to change the return statement to `self.i`.

Answer (score 3):

You first must create an instance of the class. "self" is automatically added as the first parameter, you can't pass it in yourself.

```
ben = Ben()
ben.foo()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are the various way I can think of (off the top 'o my head) to get a class attribute from an instance method:

```
class Ben:
     i = 320894
     def foo(self):
        return self.i, self.__class__.i, Ben.i, Ben.__dict__['i'], getattr(Ben,'i')

print Ben().foo()
```

Prints:

```
(320894, 320894, 320894, 320894, 320894)
```

Note the `Ben().foo()` vs `Ben.foo(self)` -- You need an instance of Ben prior to calling `foo` and `self` is implicit in the calling of `foo` as a method of that instance. If you have `Ben().foo()` the instance is created similarly to `b=Ben()` and then calling `b.foo()`

`self.i` or `Ben.i` is the most straightforward. Keep in mind that these can be different i's. `self.i` is an instance attribute and `Ben.i` is a class attribute:

```
class Ben(object):
    i = 'class i'

    def __init__(self):
        self.i='instance i'

    def foo(self):
        return ('Instance i:',self.i, getattr(self,'i'), self.__dict__['i'],
                'Class i:',self.__class__.i, getattr(Ben,'i'), Ben.i, Ben.__dict__['i'])

print Ben().foo()
```

Prints:

```
('Instance i:', 'instance i', 'instance i', 'instance i', 
 'Class i:', 'class i', 'class i', 'class i', 'class i')
```

Comment: This bypasses the OP's real problem, which was not understanding the need to create an instance (and that `self` was an implicit argument passed to the method when invoked by an instance).

Comment: I understand that. Since he had three answer that stated the same thing, I thought I would post an answer that showed actually the difference between a class attribute and an instance attribute of the same name.

Comment: @chepner: I added you helpful comments to the text. Thanks!

Comment: +1 for pointing out the difference between class and instance attributes (speaking from personal experience with a subtle bug...)